# How to combine aggregate functions in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm just learning MySQL - is there a way to combine (or nest) aggregate functions?

Given a query:

```
SELECT user, count(answer) FROM surveyValues WHERE study='a1' GROUP BY user;
```

This will give me the number of questions answered by each user. What I really want is the average number of questions answered per user...something like:

```
SELECT avg(count(answer)) FROM surveyValues WHERE study='a1';
```

What's the correct way to compute this statistic?

If this is possible, is there a way to then break this statistic down for each question? (users can answer the same question multiple times). Something like:

```
SELECT avg(count(answer)) FROM surveyValues WHERE study='a1' GROUP BY question;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use subqueries:

```
  SELECT x.user, 
         AVG(x.cnt)
    FROM (SELECT user, COUNT(answer) AS cnt
            FROM surveyValues 
           WHERE study='a1' 
        GROUP BY user) x
GROUP BY x.user
```

You can't wrap an aggregate with another aggregate.  You could wrap an analytic in an aggregate, if MySQL supported analytic/ranking/windowing functions...

Comment: Indeed, subqueries are the answer. If you have more than one query dealing with the number of answers per user, you might consider putting the subquery into a view.

Comment: Oh man, you can alias columns? SUPER-nifty. (I'm sure that sounded super-naive, but this just made my day). Thanks, works perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

yes - those all look reasonable.

Have you tried them and received unexpected results?

usually, i would expect that you also include the driving column in the select list:

```
SELECT question, avg(count(answer)) 
FROM surveyValues 
WHERE study='a1' 
GROUP BY question;
```