# MySQL: Aggregate function repeated (not one single row)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

If I have this

```
SELECT 

    TABLE1.*, 
    TABLE2.*, 
    ABS(SUM(TABLE2.PURCHASE)) PURCHASE

FROM
    CUSTOMER TABLE1
LEFT JOIN
    PURCHASES TABLE2
ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID

WHERE
   TABLE1.ID = 1
```

So... without the aggregate function `ABS(SUM(TABLE2.PURCHASE))` it gives multiple rows (as much as are number of Purchase per ID)

Obviously, with the aggregate function it gives one single row.

There's a way to have multiple rows with the same sum result repeated in each row?

---

**UPDATE** *(with solution)*:

I've found the answer and I solved the problem.

Taking its cue from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409581/how-to-combine-aggregate-functions-in-mysql?rq=1) (which I had missed)

I adapted my query to obtain the aggregate function repeated in all rows.

The final query is:

```
SELECT 

    TABLE1.*, 
    TABLE2.*, 
    (SELECT ABS(SUM(PURCHASE)) FROM PURCHASES WHERE ID = 1) PURCHASE

FROM
    CUSTOMER TABLE1
LEFT JOIN
    PURCHASES TABLE2
ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID

WHERE
   TABLE1.ID = 1
```

Comment: I'm having some hard time understanding your question. Also, `SUM` will only return one row because it adds everything in that column. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I know. I have found the solution. I modifify my question