# SQL: how can I use GROUP BY to take an aggregate of an aggregate?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query that groups by (column_a, column_b) and selects an aggregated value. I would like to then group by column_a and take an aggregate sum of the previously aggregated values.

Probably clearer with an example:

We have 3 tables: projects, devs, and contributors. Each project has many contributors, and each dev is a contributor to many projects:

```
+======== projects =========+ +====== devs =======+
+--------------+------------+ +--------+----------+
| project_name | project_id | | dev_id | dev_name |
+--------------+------------+ +--------+----------+
| parsalot     |          1 | |      1 | Ally     |
| vimplug      |          2 | |      2 | Ben      |
| gamify       |          3 | |      3 | Chris    |
+--------------+------------+ +--------+----------+
                +==== contributors ===+
                +------------+--------+
                | project_id | dev_id |
                +------------+--------+
                |          1 |      2 |
                |          1 |      3 |
                |          2 |      1 |
                |          2 |      2 |
                |          3 |      3 |
                +------------+--------+
```

I'm interested in how much work goes into each project. I could just count how many contributors each has, but I'd like to give more weight to contributions made by devs who aren't splitting their time over lots of other projects.

So vimplug is more actively developed than parsalot: each project has two contributors, but one of vimplug's (Ally) does nothing else, whereas parsalot's contributors are both splitting their time across other projects.

I've constructed a query that groups by (project, contributor) and calculates each contributors "dedication" to the project:

```
SELECT 
    projects.project_name,
    devs.dev_name,
    1 / COUNT(contributions.project_id) as dedication
FROM
    projects
        JOIN
    contributors USING (project_id)
        JOIN
    devs USING (dev_id)
        JOIN
    contributors contributions USING (dev_id)
GROUP BY projects.project_id , contributors.dev_id;
```

Which yields,

```
+--------------+----------+------------+
| project_name | dev_name | dedication |
+--------------+----------+------------+
| parsalot     | Ben      |     0.5000 |
| parsalot     | Chris    |     0.5000 |
| vimplug      | Ally     |     1.0000 |
| vimplug      | Ben      |     0.5000 |
| gamify       | Chris    |     0.5000 |
+--------------+----------+------------+
```

What I really want, though, is the total dedication for each project, i.e.

```
+--------------+------------------+
| project_name | total_dedication |
+--------------+------------------+
| gamify       |           0.5000 |
| parsalot     |           1.0000 |
| vimplug      |           1.5000 |
+--------------+------------------+
```

I (naively) tried changing my select statement to

```
SELECT 
    projects.project_name,
    SUM(1 / COUNT(contributions.project_id)) as total_dedication
```

but that doesn't work ("Invalid use of group function"). Is there a way I can do this without having to do a sub-select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
select project_name, sum(dedication)
from (<your query here>) q
group by project_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution please use the following :

```
SELECT project_name,sum(dedication) as total_dedication FROM (SELECT 
    projects.project_name,
    devs.dev_name,
    1 / COUNT(contributions.project_id) as dedication
FROM
    projects
        JOIN
    contributors USING (project_id)
        JOIN
    devs USING (dev_id)
        JOIN
    contributors contributions USING (dev_id)
GROUP BY projects.project_id , contributors.dev_id) as A GROUP BY project_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Ivan,

You asked "Is there a way I can do this without having to do a sub-select" ... is there a reason you cannot sub-select?

Unfortunately, you'll need to use a sub-select, because you cannot combine aggregate functions (which would be the only way you'd be able to accomplish this). See: [How to combine aggregate functions in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409581/how-to-combine-aggregate-functions-in-mysql)

So as the other answers have shown, you'll have to use a sub-query.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a sub-query only because I'm working in the context of a Rails app, using ActiveRecord. Subqueries are not the most straightforward thing to pull out of the ORM, but I guess there's no avoiding it in this case. I need to get more comfortable using subqueries anyway.