# SQL nested aggregate grouping error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find name of product which has sold maximum units, I've two tables, purchases and products, products has pname and pid, purchases has pid, qty(units sold).
I've managed this

```
select p.pname, sum(q.qty) from purchases q
inner join products p on p.pid=q.pid
where p.pid=q.pid
group by p.pname
order by sum(q.qty) desc
```

I'm getting the result in descending order but I need only the top most selling units, multiple products can have top most selling units. When I use

```
max(sum(q.qty))
```

I get grouping error.

Comment: What query causes an error? I.e., how do you use max(sum(q.qty))?

Comment: It would help if you could provide some sample input and expected output data, as well as how you tried to use `max(sum(q.qty))` in your query which caused the error. N.B. If you are using the ansi join syntax (e.g. `from x inner join y on (x.col = y.col)`) then you do not need to repeat the join condition in the where clause. Therefore you can get rid of the `where p.pid = q.pid` from your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine aggregate functions in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409581/how-to-combine-aggregate-functions-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte`s to do this.

1)First get the total quantity of each product
2)Then get the maximum of all those totals
3)Join it with your original query

```
with totals as (select pid, sum(qty)  totalqty from purchases group by pid)
, t1 as (select p.pid, p.pname, sum(q.qty) totqty
         from purchases q
         inner join products p on p.pid=q.pid
        group by p.pname) 
, t2 as (select max(totalqty) maxtotal from totals)
select pname, totqty
from t1 
join t2 on t1.totqty = t2.maxtotal
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to derive the values first using a common table expression.

Simply put you can't wrap aggregates in other aggregates.  You may be able to wrap an aggregate around an analytic however.

```
with cte as (select p.pname, sum(q.qty) from purchases q
inner join products p on p.pid=q.pid
where p.pid=q.pid
group by p.pname
order by sum(q.qty) desc)
Select pname, max(purchases)
from cte
group by pname
```

Answer (score 0):

Analytics can simplify this for you. If you have more than one product with the same sum(qty) and that happens to be the max(sum(qty)), then this should get you them:

```
select pname, quantity
FROM (
select p.pname
     , sum(q.qty) quantity
     ,rank() over (order by sum(q.qty desc) ranking
from purchases q
 inner join products p on p.pid=q.pid
group by p.pname
)
where ranking = 1
```