# Aggregate result of MySQL aggregate query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table containing many millions of call records that I need to run aggregate stats on. The table looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| id       | calltype | client_id | extension_number | flow | partyid     | start               | answer              | duration | disposion | sipcallid                                  | did         |
+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| 35080566 | out      |       139 | 2222*050         | in   | 01123334455 | 2015-11-12 17:11:10 | 2015-11-12 17:11:10 |        4 | ANSWERED  | 20202911-3656337069-994458@sip.example.com | 01932855644 |
| 35077822 | out      |       139 | 2222*603         | in   | 02114455784 | 2015-11-12 16:37:41 | 2015-11-12 16:37:41 |       27 | ANSWERED  | 20138716-3656335055-417971@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35077821 | out      |       139 | 2222*603         | in   | 02114455784 | 2015-11-12 16:38:08 | 2015-11-12 16:38:08 |       80 | ANSWERED  | 20138716-3656335055-417971@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35077820 | local    |       139 | 2222*747         | in   | 2222*605    | 2015-11-12 16:38:09 | 2015-11-12 16:38:09 |       79 | ANSWERED  | 20138716-3656335055-417971@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35077346 | out      |       139 | 2222*603         | in   | 07841254789 | 2015-11-12 16:26:15 | 2015-11-12 16:26:15 |       27 | ANSWERED  | 20113840-3656334365-407195@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35077345 | out      |       139 | 2222*603         | in   | 07841254789 | 2015-11-12 16:26:42 | 2015-11-12 16:26:42 |      527 | ANSWERED  | 20113840-3656334365-407195@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35077344 | local    |       139 | 2222*746         | in   | 2222*609    | 2015-11-12 16:26:43 | 2015-11-12 16:26:43 |      526 | ANSWERED  | 20113840-3656334365-407195@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35065079 | out      |       139 | 2222*603         | in   | 02415785414 | 2015-11-12 14:37:21 | 2015-11-12 14:37:21 |       21 | ANSWERED  | 19848872-3656327834-411032@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35065078 | out      |       139 | 2222*603         | in   | 02415785414 | 2015-11-12 14:37:42 | 2015-11-12 14:37:42 |      776 | ANSWERED  | 19848872-3656327834-411032@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
| 35065077 | local    |       139 | 2222*744         | in   | 2222*604    | 2015-11-12 14:37:42 | 2015-11-12 14:37:42 |      776 | ANSWERED  | 19848872-3656327834-411032@sip.example.com | 01123334455 |
+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

I need to run a query to aggregate the data on a daily basis. This should be simple but as you can see from the data, there are multiple rows for one public call (the bottom three rows for example are different legs of the same call - this is apparent as they all have the same SIP call id). The time the call started (i.e. ringing) is the `start` and the answer time is `answer`.

I need to produce the following stats:

Total number of calls per DID

No. of calls answered < 5 seconds

No. of calls answered > 10 seconds

I have a query that calculates `MAX(answer)-MAX(start)` which gives a tally of those answered in the relevant time bands, but I cannot work out how to aggregate the output of that to give me daily figures.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT ch.did "Inbound DDI", 
  DATE(ch.start) Date, 
  IF((MAX(answer)-MIN(start)) < 5, 1 , 0),
  IF((MAX(answer)-MIN(start)) BETWEEN 5 AND 10, 1 , 0),
  IF((MAX(answer)-MIN(start)) > 10, 1 , 0)
  sipcallid
FROM 
  call_history ch
WHERE 
  flow = 'in' 
  AND ch.did <> ""
  AND ch.client_client_id = 1207 
  AND ch.duration > 0
  AND ch.disposition = "ANSWERED"
  AND DATE(start) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
GROUP BY 
  ch.sipcallid;
```

Is there a way to aggregate the output of this, or do I have to script it? I can see that I could do this in Python for example.

Comment: Argh. More searching reveals the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409581/how-to-combine-aggregate-functions-in-mysql. I fear scripting may be the only way forward.

Comment: The other thing I have discovered which appears to help are temporary MySQL tables thus: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/ I can foresee a situation where I dump the 1st pass aggregate data to a temp table, and then query that - therefore no scripting as such.

Answer (score 0):

As per linked suggestion you could use subquery to achieve your goal and and avoid python scripting. The query may look something like this:

```
SELECT
  agg.Date,
  SUM(agg.short),
  SUM(agg.long)
FROM (
SELECT ch.did "Inbound DDI", 
  DATE(ch.start) Date, 
  IF((MAX(answer)-MIN(start)) < 5, 1 , 0) as 'short',
  IF((MAX(answer)-MIN(start)) BETWEEN 5 AND 10, 1 , 0) as 'avg',
  IF((MAX(answer)-MIN(start)) > 10, 1 , 0) as 'long',
  sipcallid
FROM 
  call_history ch
WHERE 
  flow = 'in' 
  AND ch.did <> ""
  AND ch.duration > 0
  AND ch.disposion = "ANSWERED"
GROUP BY 
  ch.sipcallid
) agg
GROUP BY agg.Date
```

You can try this query at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/855a0e/8)

Comment: thanks this is useful, only problem I have is due to the size of  `call_history` the subqueries will likely be too slow to be of use. I have experimented with this but so far failed.

Comment: Also you may use a kind of magic and try to use `COUNT` over `sipcallid` column like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/855a0e/23 But I'm not sure in this solution