# Get average count of GroupBy Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to make reviews system and  I want to get the average  of the count(id)  while using group by

if I use count with group by  it works and I get

```
return $comments  = Comment::select('rating',DB::raw('count(id)  as 
total_reviews'))->where('product_id', $id)->where('shop_name', $shop)-
>groupBy('rating')->get();
```

results

```
  [
{
"rating": 1,
"total_reviews": 1
},
{
"rating": 2,
"total_reviews": 2
},
{
"rating": 3,
"total_reviews": 2
},
{
"rating": 4,
"total_reviews": 6
},
{
"rating": 5,
"total_reviews": 61
}
]
```

but when I add avg() I get an error

```
return $comments = Comment::select('rating',DB::raw('avg(count(id))
as total_reviews'))->where('product_id', $id)->where('shop_name', $shop)-
>groupBy('rating')->get();
```

> General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select
>   `rating`, avg(count(id)) as total_reviews from `comments`.....

Answer (score 0):

There a good example in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) which does something similiar check this out:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
```

Try it this way using the DB facade and tell me what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can not combine aggregate functions in Mysql, You have to use subqueries:
[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409581/how-to-combine-aggregate-functions-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to average the count for each row, which doesn't make sense.
Try using a subselect: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f4f8e/4

Answer (score 0):

I think nested aggregate functions are not supported. So, you can try collection average method like this:

```
$average_rating = Comment::select('rating','product_id','shop_name',
                   DB::raw('count(id) as total_counts'))
                  ->where('product_id', $id)
                  ->where('shop_name', $shop)
                  ->groupBy('rating')
                  ->get()
                  ->avg('total_counts');
```

Here, up to `get()` you will get collection which contains total count of each rating and then `avg()` will search `total_counts` values and average them.

I hope you understand. You can see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-avg