# How to combine aggregated queries with different joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409581/how-to-combine-aggregate-functions-in-mysql) and [this jooq.org post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/), trying to figure out how to do my combined aggregations in **MySQL**, but not having much luck.

Here are my 2 queries:

```
select a.IsTestAgency, a.ID, a.AgencyName, a.CreateDate, count(*) AS Agents
from Users u
join Agencies a
on u.AgencyID = a.ID
group by a.IsTestAgency, a.ID, a.AgencyName, a.CreateDate
order by a.IsTestAgency, a.AgencyName;
```

Results:

[image]

and:

```
select a.IsTestAgency, a.ID, a.AgencyName, a.CreateDate, count(*) AS Certs
from Certificates c
join Agencies a
on c.AgencyID = a.ID
group by a.IsTestAgency, a.ID, a.AgencyName, a.CreateDate
order by a.IsTestAgency, a.AgencyName;
```

Results:

[image]

You can see that the columns and columns' datatypes match. I'd like to combine these into a single query and show the `Agents` count and the `Certs` count side-by-side, since those are the only 2 column values that are different in the result sets.

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by `JOIN`ing to tables of `COUNT`s:

```
select a.IsTestAgency, a.ID, a.AgencyName, a.CreateDate, u.Agents, c.Certs
from Agencies a
join (select AgencyID, COUNT(*) as Agents from Users group by AgencyID) u on u.AgencyID = a.ID
join (select AgencyID, COUNT(*) as Certs from Certficates group by AgencyID) c on c.AgencyID = a.ID
order by a.IsTestAgency, a.AgencyName;
```

This removes the need to `group by` in the top query and also saves having to do two subquery counts for each row of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.*, 
       (select count(*)
        from users u
        where u.AgencyID = a.ID
       ) as users_count,
       (select count(*)
        from Certificates c
        where c.AgencyID = a.ID
       ) as certificates_count
from Agencies a
order by a.IsTestAgency, a.AgencyName;
```

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . Not at all.  That shouldn't be there.